# Copy a uint8_t array to a struct

Tags: c, memcpy, string-literals

I have this array

```
uint8_t *buffer = "JOHN:DOE:010119:M:FOO:BAR";
```

and I want to copy it field by field to data structure

```
typedef struct{
  uint8_t firstName[5];
  uint8_t pad1;
  uint8_t lastName[4];
  uint8_t pad2;
  uint8_t dateOfBirth[7];
  uint8_t pad3;
  uint8_t genre;
  uint8_t pad4;
  uint8_t car[4];
  uint8_t pad5;
  uint8_t phone[4];
  uint8_t pad6;
}DataStructTypeDef;
```

Let's say that all lengths are fixed (eg. `firstName` is always composed of 4 characters, `lastName` of 3 etc ...)

I used this approach:

```
DataStructTypeDef foo;
memcpy((void *)&foo, (void *)buffer, sizeof(DataStructTypeDef));
```

When I try to print `dateOfBirth` it shows the whole array starting from 01012019 like this

```
int main(void)
{
  DataStructTypeDef foo;
  memcpy((void *)&foo, (void *)buffer, sizeof(DataStructTypeDef));
  printf("%s", foo.dateOfBirth); // It prints 010119:M:FOO:BAR
//printf("%s", foo.dateOfBirth); // Expected value 010119
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try manually setting the paddings to `'\0'` after copying, like `foo.pad1 = '\0';`

Comment: @Blaze I tried to change the padding from : to \0. The problem is that in some cases, I have a field that starts with a digit like this :01012019:. If I change the : to a \0 it will be \001012019.

Comment: Warning : "firstName is always composed of 4 characters,lastName of 3 etc ..." is false, you missed the place for the null character ending them

Comment: @bruno I am using a padding bit instead of the \0 character.

Comment: @zerocoldTUN if you do not end the strings by a null charac you will not be able to use the standard functions supposing that by is present, so no printf / strcpy / strdup/ .... `uint8_t lastName[3];` means _lastName_ contains 1 or 2 characters then the \0, not 3 characters

Comment: @xing I edited the post. My bad.

Comment: @bruno I added 1 to all fields (firstName[4] --> firstName[5] etc ..). still have the same problem

Comment: @xing My goal is to fill the structure not to print its values. printing is just for debugging purposes.

Comment: What is your question? Are you aware of how C mimiks "string"s, which in fact are no data type in C. You might like to read about the concept of *`0`-terminated `char`-arrays*.

Comment: "*using a padding bit*" what you call a "*bit*" in fact is a `byte`, or to be more precise a `unit8_t`.

Comment: Note: Casts are not needed in C for this code, Suggest using sizeof object. Simplification: `memcpy(&foo, buffer, sizeof foo);` Easy to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: Aside everything mentioned so far, if going on this route using a struct, take care it is packed, because else strange things might happen due to additional padding introduced by the compiler itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `char array` members you are copying are not null terminated, `printf("%s",` will not know when it has encountered the end of each string.

This can be controlled in `printf` by limiting the amount of characters that print...

For example:

```
printf("%.*s", (int)sizeof(foo.dateOfBirth), foo.dateOfBirth);
```

An equivalent would be:

```
printf("%.6s", food.dateOfBirth);
```

`.*` specifies the "precision" of characters you want to print. So in your case, `dateOfBirth` = precision/size 6.

Comment: `%.*s` specifies the **maximum** number of characters to output. output will stop at a null terminator if one is present before this limit.

Answer (score 2):

With the fixed struct of

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t firstName[4];
    uint8_t pad1;
    uint8_t lastName[3];
    uint8_t pad2;
    uint8_t dateOfBirth[6];
    uint8_t pad3;
    uint8_t genre;
    uint8_t pad4;
    uint8_t car[3];
    uint8_t pad5;
    uint8_t phone[3];
    uint8_t pad6;
}DataStructTypeDef;
```

This works for me:

```
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t *buffer = "JOHN" "\0" "DOE" "\0" "010119" "\0" "M" "\0" "FOO" "\0" "BAR";
    DataStructTypeDef foo;
    memcpy((void *)&foo, (void *)buffer, sizeof(DataStructTypeDef));
    printf("%s", foo.dateOfBirth); // Expected value 01012019
}
```

The buffer looks horribly mangled because if I put `"\0" "010119"` as `"\0010119"`, it's interpreting the escape the wrong way. A better solution would probably be to keep it as one and fully write out the octal sequence as `\000`:

```
uint8_t *buffer = "JOHN\000DOE\000010119\000M\000FOO\000BAR";
```

Here, each `\000` becomes a null byte and it doesn't clash with the `010119` following one of the escape sequences.

Alternatively, it works if I take the original buffer string of `"JOHN:DOE:010119:M:FOO:BAR"` and just replace all the `:` after copying, like this:

```
foo.pad1 = foo.pad2 = foo.pad3 = foo.pad4 = foo.pad5 = foo.pad6 = '\0';
```

Comment: Are you really trying to initialize the scalar `uint8_t pad1` field with the *string* "\0"?

Comment: @AndrewHenle no, those strings get automatically concatenated into one string at compile time. So all those `"\0"` translate to one `\0` each. I only did it this way because otherwise it would interpret it as a different literal when there's a a `0` right after a `\0` in the literal.

Comment: Ah. Got it.  I didn't catch the missing `,` between the fields.

Comment: Re “it's interpreting the escape the wrong way”: In C, an octal escape sequence has one to three octal digits. The compiler correctly interprets `”\001"` as 1. Zero can be designated with `”\000"`.

Comment: So I could make `\0` work in the string literal by turning all instances of it into  `\000`... good to know, thanks!

Comment: All those "\0" translate into '\0''\0' and with this exceeding the member to be initialised. UB?

Comment: @alk: no, only a final "\0" would translate to 2 null bytes. concatenated strings do not have extra embedded null bytes, only the ones that appear explicitly.

Comment: @chqrlie: You are right. My mind introduced non existing commas. Please excuse.

Answer (score 2):

1. Modify your structure

Add an extra byte to each field to accommodate the '\0' character. For e.g. use

```
uint8_t firstName[5];
```

instead of

```
uint8_t firstName[4];
```

2. Parse the fields individually and end each field with '\0'

Instead of copying the entire buffer in one go, copy the elements one by one. Since, the size of each field is fixed, the offset from the start of the buffer is fixed and this makes the job of parsing easier.

Answer (score 1):

After `memcpy` add this: `foo.pad1 = foo.pad2 = foo.pad3 = foo.pad4 = foo.pad5 = 0;`. But I hope this is exercise, not a real structure for real job.

Comment: "I hope this is exercise, not a real structure for real job."
What's wrong with it?

Comment: @zerocoldTUN For example: 1) do you expect to use only names where first name is always 4 letters and last name always 3 letters? 2) Instead of `pad1` and `pad2` you can expand `firstName` and `lastName` with 1 byte for trailing zero. 3) It is normal to use `char` array for name, not byte array.

Comment: In fact that was just an example. I am not treating first names and last names. In fact I have an EEPROM (memory) and I am using in it to store data for my product. Product ID, Manufacture date, Batch number etc ... Reading data from the memory returns an array of characters, and I am the one who defined those fields. I am using fixed-length fields for each data for example: the date is always DDMMYY and January, 1st is not written like this: 1119. It's always 010119. So yeah: I am 100% sure that all field sizes are fix and that's why I wanted to store it directly to data structure.

Comment: @zerocoldTUN: "*100% sure that all field sizes are fix*" What the use of the colons (`:`) inside the data, though?

Comment: @alk, you are right. I can remove them. In fact, at first I used \0. I had a problem with fields that start with a digit like :010119. SO I changed the \0 with a : to test. I forgot to delete them though ..

Comment: @zerocoldTUN: `'0'` and `\0` are *not* the same.